# Closed Gallery without closing app [Android]

Tags: android, camera, back

I'm new in developers world. I have some problems with one issues. I upload a photo from my Gallery from on CreateChooser, but if I have want to go back because I realized that I don't want to upload the photo my app finish at all And I don't know how to make that when I closing the Gallery (chooser) goes to the previous screen or any fragment.

This is my code:

```
private void mostrarDialogOpciones() {
        final CharSequence[] opciones={"Elegir imagen de Galería","Cancelar"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Elige una opción");
        builder.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                  if (opciones[i].equals("Elegir imagen de Galería")){

                           String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg"};
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                                .setType("image/*")
                                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);

                        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione:"),COD_SELECCIONA);
                    }else{
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Elija una imagen válida",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                //}
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

And this my onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case COD_SELECCIONA:
            Uri miPath=data.getData();
            imgFoto.setImageURI(miPath);

            try {
                bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(),miPath);
                imgFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
    bitmap=redimensionarImagen(bitmap,600,800);
}
```

Forgive my english. I hope you can help me! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For that, you don't need to do anything from code. Because when gallery open with the help of intent from your activity or fragment and you pressed back button it back without any disturbance to your relevant activity. So it's handled itself.

And if you want to do anything when you don't choose any image from gallery and just back from there you can check it into your **onActivityResult** with the **result code**. If **resultCode != RESULT_OK** that means you have not chosen an image from the gallery.

Comment: Thank you! I think that but when I pressed back button my app close at all, so I don't know how to handled de back button. I tried with resultCode just like you said, but I don't know how to back on my previous fragment because I work with fragments.